# how do I pull specific data from a couple of lines in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: Imagage of dataset]

If I wanted to see all prices from dealer "B" how could I query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT price FROM TableName WHERE dealer = 'B'
```

From your example set, this will return 2 rows, with 1 column each.  3.99 and 1.45.